# Count list elements

Tags: c++, linked-list, counter

I'm programming a doubly linked list, in which I read strings from a given file.

So therefore I wrote a class called Node in which I store a string (the read word) and some integers for the wordlength and other parameters.

After I read all strings form the file, I open a second file and again read out every word and compare the word with the strings in the linked list. After that I store every found word in a result file.

Now I want to show the user which position in the text the found word had, for example:

> "Found the word on the 200 place in the text file"

Therefore I created a counter, which is incremented every time a new node is created. My problem now is that my counter is just counting how many nodes are created at whole. So I just see there are about 56000 nodes created, but I can't store the number of the node.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I didn't try to decrement the counter, because I never delete a node.

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
class Word
{
    public:
    Word (string inputstring = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int l = 0, Word *n = 0, Word *p = 0 ) : word (inputstring), book (b), chapter (c), length (l), next (n), prev (p)
    {
      ++counter;
    }
    int book;
    int chapter;
    int length;
    string word;
    Word *next;
    Word *prev;

    static size_t howMany()
    {
      return counter;
    }

    private:
      static size_t counter;
};

size_t Word::counter;

int main ()
{
    string inputstring = "empty";
    string compare = "empty";
    int l1 = 0;
    int book = 0;
    int chapter = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Word *p = 0;
    Word *x = 0;
    Word *start = 0;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("Beispieltext.txt");

    ofstream outfile;

    if (!file) cout << ("can't open input file");
    else         cout << "File: Beispieltext.txt open\n";

    // create nodes
    while (file >> inputstring)
    {
        l1 = (int)inputstring.length();

        if ( (!(inputstring[0] >= 'A' && inputstring[0] <= 'Z')) && (!(inputstring[0] >= 'a' && inputstring[0] <= 'z'))) inputstring = inputstring.substr(1,l1--); // l1-- reduce length
        while ( (!(inputstring[l1-1] >= 'A' && inputstring[l1-1] <= 'Z')) && (!(inputstring[l1-1] >= 'a' && inputstring[l1-1] <= 'z'))) inputstring = inputstring.substr(0,--l1); // --l1 go till n-1

        // book?
        if (std::strncmp(inputstring.data(), "BOOK", 4) == 0) ++book, chapter = 0/*, cout << "\nBook Nr.: " << book << "\n"*/;

        // Chapter?
        if (std::strncmp(inputstring.data(), "CHAPTER", 7) == 0) ++chapter/*, cout << "chapter: " << chapter << "\n"*/;

        if (p == NULL)
        {
            p = new Word (inputstring);
        } else
        {
            x = new Word (inputstring, book, chapter, l1, 0, p);
            p->next = x;
            p = x;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    cout << "File: Beispieltext.txt closed!\n";

    // n...0
    for (; p; p = p->prev) start = p; // go to start

    // Open compare file 1
    file.open("Suchbegriffe_1.txt");
    if (!file) cout << "Can't open compare file!\n";
    else        cout << "File: Suchbegriffe.txt open!\n";

    // Open result file 1
    outfile.open("Result_1.txt");
    if(!outfile) cout << "Can't open Result_1.txt file!\n";
    else        cout << "File: Result_1.txt open!\n";

    while (file >> compare)
    {
        l1 = (int)compare.length();
        // Search
        x = start;
        // 0...n go to end
        for (; x; x = x->next)
        {
            if (l1 == x->length)
            {
                if (compare == x->word)
                {
                    outfile << "Word: " << compare << " found in book Nr.: " << x->book << ", chapter: " << x->chapter << "!\n";
                    outfile << "Word: " << compare << " is the " << x->howMany() << " Word in the book.\n";
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        outfile << "Word: " << compare  << ", " << count << "x found!\n";
        count = 0;
    }
    file.close();
    cout << "File: Suchbegriffe_1.txt closed!\n";
    outfile.close();
    cout << "File: Result.txt closed!\n";

    // Open compare file 2
    file.open("Suchbegriffe_2.txt");
    if (!file) cout << "Can't open compare file!\n";
    else        cout << "File: Suchbegriffe.txt open!\n";

    // Open result file 2
    outfile.open("Result_2.txt");
    if (!outfile) cout << "Can't open Result_2 file!\n";
    else        cout << "File: Result_2.txt open!\n";

    while (file >> compare)
    {
        l1 = (int)compare.length();

        // Search
        x = start;
        // 0...n go to end
        for (; x; x = x->next)
        {
            if (l1 == x->length)
            {
                if (compare == x->word)
                {
                    outfile << "Word: " << compare << " found in book Nr.: " << x->book << ", chapter: " << x->chapter << "!\n";
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        outfile << "Word: " << compare  << ", " << count << "x found!\n";
        count = 0;
    }
    file.close();
    cout << "File: Suchbegriffe_2.txt closed!\n";

    outfile.close();
    cout << "File: Result_2.txt closed!\n";
}
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code (and format it correctly) instead of expecting people to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Have you tried to decrement the counter in destructor?

Comment: @Jepessen, that won't change the fact that every node shares a single global counter so can't possibly return a different ID for each node

Comment: In your constructor what is `string inputstring = 0` supposed to do? That will create a string containing a null pointer, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the full code. Declaring all your variables at the top of the function is poor style that comes from old C code, but hasn't even been necessary in C for 15 years. e.g. if you declare `int count = 0;` inside the `while` loop then it's only in scope where required and  you don't need to zero it at the end of the loop. Also closing your `fstream` objects is redundant, the destructor does that.

Comment: @Jonathan Then increase the global counter and then store that value in a local class member.

Comment: @Jepessen, right, that's one solution. Simply making other changes to the global counter isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem now is that my counter is just counting how many nodes are created at whole.

Yes, because you have a single global counter that counts nodes created.

> So I just see there are about 56000 nodes created, but I can't store the number of the node.

If you want a different number for every node then you can't store a single number in one place and expect it to have several different values!

You need to

- **either** store a number in each node as a member variable, not a static variable (but make sure you keep them all correct if nodes are added or removed from the beginning or middle of the list, and if you're ever going to have two lists in the program at once make sure the first node in the list has number 0 i.e. it must be the number *in that list* not just the global counter of allocated nodes.)
- **or**, much simpler, just keep a counter as you walk the list and increment it for every node you see. You're already counting the number of matched words, why can't you just keep a total count of all inspected words, including the non-matches?

For example:

```
while (file >> compare)
{
    int checked = 0;
    int found = 0;
    for (Word* x = start; x; x = x->next)
    {
        if (compare == x->word)
        {
            outfile << "Word: " << compare << " found in book Nr.: " << x->book << ", chapter: " << x->chapter << " at word " << checked << "!\n";
            found++;
        }
        checked++;
    }
    outfile << "Word: " << compare  << ", " << found << "x found!\n";
}
```

Note that I declare variables inside the loop (not at the top of the function) and don't bother checking the word length, because comparing `std::string` already does that. Why do you even store the length in the `Word` class? `x->word.length()` tells you the length, you don't need to store it explicitly.

Also, this is crazy:

```
for (; p; p = p->prev) start = p; // go to start
```

This goes backwards through a large list to find the start ... just set the start when you allocate the first node and keep it!

```
    x = new Word (inputstring, book, chapter, l1, 0, p);
    if (!start)
        start = x;  // remember the start
    p->next = x;
    p = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `counter` is static, meaning it is the only one in the class.

So say I'm reading in 3 words: "a", "b", and "c". When I call `howMany` on "a" it will return 3, "b" and "c"'s `howMany` will also return 3.

I would suggest keeping all your `Word`s in a `std::vector` and just calling `std::vector.size()` to get the `Word` count. The I would remove the `static` from `counter` and `howMany` and pass the word count in as a parameter to the `Word` constructor, so you can store it in your `counter` member variable.

Comment: +1, although I suspect the OP has been told to write a linked list class, so although your suggestion is a better idea, it won't be allowed :) No need to store a count in the `Word`, you can find its position in the vector by subtracting the address of the first element in the vector. That has the advantage that you don't need to update the count in every element when you add/remove elements in the middle of the vector

Comment: @JonathanWakely that would be more ideal. I was just trying to retrofit rather than go for an overhaul, cause I wasn't sure where that would end :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you store a an integer value along with the word you find, in the result file. And display it while printing the result.

Or you can use a position variable inside the node class to determine it's position.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix:

```
class Word
{
  public:
    Word (string inputstring = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int l = 0, Word *n = 0, Word *p = 0 )
      : word (inputstring), book (b), chapter (c), length (l), next (n), prev (p)
    {
        currCont = ++counter;
    }
    int book;
    int chapter;
    int length;
    string word;
    Word *next;
    Word *prev;
    int currCont;

    size_t howMany()
    {
        return currCont;
    }

  private:
    static size_t counter;
};

// ...later...

    x = start;
    // 0...n go to end
    for (; x; x = x->next)
    {
        if (l1 == x->length)
        {
            if (compare == x->word)
            {
                outfile << "Word: " << compare << " is the " << x->howMany() << " Word in the book.\n";
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    outfile << "Word: " << compare  << ", " << count << "x found!\n";
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply your changes, but in the line 'int curcounter;' I get the error message:   32 9 main.cpp [Error] invalid use of member 'Word::curcounter' in static member function

Comment: `howMany` should not be `static`